# file.creation formatting in c#

Tags: c#

i have a fileinfo array which loads jpegs from a folder.

When I add them to the list box using the creationtime property it adds both the date and time, for example: "07/07/2010 14:28"

Here is the code I use:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in files5)
    {

      sessionframeslstLISTBOX.Items.Add(fi.CreationTime);
    }
```

I want it so that It just says the time, ege: "14:28"

How can I format the string before its added to the listbox so that it omits the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sessionframeslstLISTBOX.Items.Add(fi.CreationTime.ToShortTimeString());
```

Comment: Though the ShortTime pattern will depend on the culture and may not be in 24 hour format.

Comment: thanks, oh i feel so dumb i had never used that method before :O

Answer (score 0):

Use the format specifier: `"{0:t}"` from String.Format, or `"t"` from your `DateTime` object's `.ToString()` or you can also use `.ToShortTimeString()` from your `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.ToString(format)` method.

[Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for format.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
sessionframeslstLISTBOX.Items.Add(fi.CreationTime.ToString("t"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fi.CreationTime.ToShortTimeString()
```

That should do the trick for you.  To show it in your own code it would look like this:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in files5)
{

  sessionframeslstLISTBOX.Items.Add(fi.CreationTime.ToShortTimeString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the CreationTime by calling ToString on it and passing it a format string.

It looks like you probably want `fi.CreationTime.ToString("HH:mm")`, but look at the other format strings available:

[Standard Time and Date Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

[Custom Time and Date Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

String.Format("{0:hh mm}", fi.CreationTime)

Comment: That'll put the day and the minute... are you sure you didnt mean {0:HH mm}